# How can I use templates here to avoid using std::function in this code

Tags: c++

I have a class that describes a certain type of function (here I mean function in the mathematical, and not programming sense). Within this class I have a method called `integrate(...)` which uses `std::function` and `std::string` to determine exactly what to do. I know the way I have done things is poor, and I would like some ideas on how I could code this better. Preferably I would like to avoid using `std::function` and use templates instead. Below is a simplification of what I have that shows the basic idea.

I also don't think what I have is very efficient. The integration method can be quite costly and is called many times, so better efficiency would be quite helpful.

```
class SomeFunction {
public:
     SomeFunction(SomeParameter param) { // do constructor type things // }
     double value(double coord) { // return the value of the function // }
     double derivative(double coord) { // return the derivative of the function // }

     double integrate(std::string case, SomeType domain_of_integration) {
          std::function<double(double)> to_be_integrated;
          double some_other_parameter;

          if (case == "value") {
               to_be_integrated = [&](double x) -> double {
                    return this->value(x);
               };
               some_other_parameter = foo;
          }
          else if (case == "derivative") {
               to_be_integrated = [&](double x) -> double {
                    return this->derivative(x);
               };
               some_other_parameter = bar;
          }
          else {
               std::cerr << "ERROR - invalid integral\n";
               exit(1);
          }

          // evaluate the integral using 
          // to_be_integrated, some_other_parameter and domain_of_integration
     }

private:
     // some member variables //
};
```

Comment: Is `case` a run-time value?

Comment: The function integrate(...) is called several times from several files, but each case is known at compile time.

Comment: Then you could split into `integrate_value` and `integrate_derivative`. Possibly combine that with Jarods answer to remove code duplication.

Comment: I actually have more than two cases though. I have "value", "gradient", "hessian", "grad_dot_n" and "laplace". Writing a function for each seems excessive. Although, with Jarod's answer each would now be quite short so could be an option.

Comment: You can also pass an `enum` to `integrate` as a template parameter and use `if constexpr` to remove run-time cost. `integrate<IntegrateTypes::Value>(...);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create sub-function:

```
private:
template <typename F>
double integrate_impl(F to_be_integrated,
                      double some_other_parameter,
                      SomeType domain_of_integration)
{
    // ...
    // evaluate the integral using 
    // to_be_integrated, some_other_parameter and domain_of_integration
}
public:
double integrate(std::string option, SomeType domain_of_integration) {
     if (option == "value") {
           return integrate_impl([&](double x) -> double {
                return this->value(x);
           }, foo, domain_of_integration);
      }
      else if (option == "derivative") {
           return integrate_impl([&](double x) -> double {
                return this->derivative(x);
           }, bar, domain_of_integration);
      } else {
           std::cerr << "ERROR - invalid integral\n";
           exit(1);
      }
}
```

Comment: Do you think this would be more efficient? I have heard std::function has significant overhead.

Comment: Overhead of `std::function` is similar to a virtual call.